# If $f(x) = x\cdot g(x)$, then show that the Maclaurin polynomial for $f$ is the Maclaurin polynomial for $g$, multiplied by $x$.

Tags: calculus, summation, taylor-expansion

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be functions such that $f(x) = x\cdot g(x)$.  Can somebody show why the Maclaurin polynomial of $f(x)$ is the same as the Maclaurin polynomial of $g(x)$, multiplied by $x$?

Here is what I got:

In the following, $T^f_{n,0}(x)$ and $T^g_{n,0}(x)$ denote the $n$-th Maclaurin polynomials for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

[image: The work I did]

What's confusing me is that the last term of $T^f(x)$ is not the same as the last term of $x\cdot T^g(x)$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I don't understand your second expression: are you setting up $Tf(x)$ or $Tg(x)$ there?

Comment: Yes, I just set up the two Maclaurin polynomial for Tf(x) and Tg(x)

Comment: I uploaded a picture of my work to make it easier to understand what I am asking for.

Comment: In order for the degrees to match, the identity you want is $$T^f_{n,0} = x\cdot T^g_{n-1,0}$$ That is, the $n$-th Maclaurin polynomial for $f$ is $x$ multiplied by the $(n-1)$-th polynomial for $g$.

Comment: @Blue can you explain why that is the case. Why doesn't the the nth term of Tf(x) match with the nth term of Tg(x)?

Comment: They don't match because $T^f_{n,0}$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial, and so is $T^g_{n,0}$. That's what the $n$ represents. It cannot be that $T^f_n = x\cdot T^g_n$, because the degree on the right is $1+n$. You have to account for the extra degree from the $x$ factor by using a one-degree-smaller polynomial for $g$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, since the $n$-th Maclaurin polynomial $T_{n,0}$ is degree $n$, the desired identity must be

$$T^f_{n,0}(x) = x\,T^g_{n-1,0}(x) \qquad\left(\;\text{or}\;\;T^f_{n+1,0}(x) = x\,T^g_{n,0}(x)\;\right)$$

in order for the degrees of the polynomials on each side to match.

You can compress the derivation this way, where I'll save space by not writing the "$(0)$" in "$f^k(0)$" and "$g^k(0)$": $$T^f_{n,0}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^nf^k\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^nkg^{k-1}\frac{x^k}{k!}=x\sum_{k=1}^ng^{k-1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}g^k\frac{x^k}{k!} = x\;T^g_{n-1,0}(x)$$ (Note the shifting summation indices, which the reader should justify.) Looked at this way, the form of $T^g_{n-1,0}(x)$ appears pretty naturally.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Thank you for explaining this so well.